# Why Resharper not detect unused references in empty MSVS 2015 console app?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper-9.1

If you try to create empty console app in MSVS 2013 and remove unused references, then only two of them remain: System and System.Core.

But if you preform same task in new MSVS 2015 Community (14.0.23107.0) then nothing except Microsoft.CSharp would be removed:

[image: Removing unused references in MSVS 2015]

I think that it is quite strange behavior. All that (actually unused) references used in some temp code file called **.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cs**:

[image: Only one unused reference detected]

And it is fine if you remove unused references manually - project builds without problems.

The question is: what purpose of that temporary auto-generated file and why it has so many dependencies? *It hasn't actually, that is why I suppose that it is bug or something...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper Team will investigate it https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-446156

Comment: Do you have same issue?

Comment: Yes, I do, for sure the same behavior.

Comment: Ah, you are from JetBrains support, thank you for your attention :-) 
I close my question in that case - from now I can use bug tracker to monitor problem status.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no a workaround for such issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too. I deleted that temp file and generally cleaned up my temp folder. Then things worked as you'd expect.